# Python - Regex - match characters between certain characters

Tags: python, regex, character, match, findall

I have a textfile and i want to match/findall/parse all characters that are between certain characters (**[\n"** **text to match** **"\n]**). The text itself can differ a lot from each other in respect to the structure and characters they contain (they can contain every possible char there is).

I posted this question before (sorry for the duplicate) but so far the problem couldnt be solved, so now i am trying to be even more precise about the problem.

The text in the file is build up like this:

```
    test =""" 
        [
        "this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."
        ], 
        [
        "like *.;#]§< and many "" more."
        ], 
        [
        "plus there are even
newlines

in it."
        ]"""
```

My desired output should be a list (for example) with each text in between the seperators as an element, like the following:

```
['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.', 'like *.;#]§< and many "" more.', 'plus there are even newlines in it.']
```

I tried to solve it with Regex and two solutions with the according output i came up with:

```
my_list = re.findall(r'(?<=\[\n {8}\").*(?=\"\n {8}\])', test)
print (my_list)

['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.', 'like *.;#]§< and many "" more.']
```

well this one was close. Its listing the first two elements as its supposed to but unfortunately not the third one as it has newlines within.

```
my_list = re.findall(r'(?<=\[\n {8}\")[\s\S]*(?=\"\n {8}\])', test)
print (my_list)

['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."\n        ], \n        [\n        "like *.;#]§< and many "" more."\n        ], \n        [\n        "plus there are even\nnewlines\n        \n        in it.']
```

okay this time every element is included but the list has only one element in it and the lookahead doesnt seem to be working as i thought it would.

So whats the right Regex to use to get my desired output?
Why does the second approach not include the lookahead?

Or is there even a cleaner, faster way to get what i want (beautifulsoup or other methods?)?

I am very thankful for any help and hints.

i am using python 3.6.

Comment: Your expected output has "newlins" in the string - I'm assuming that's a typo and you meant "newlines", right?

Comment: yep youre right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `DOTALL` flag for matching newlines

```
print(re.findall(r'\[\n\s+"(.*?)"\n\s+\]', test, re.DOTALL))
```

Output

```
['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.', 'like *.;#]§< and many "" more.', 'plus there are even\nnewlines\n\nin it.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern

```
(?s)\[[^"]*"(.*?)"[^]"]*\]
```

to capture every element within the `"`s inside the brackets:

https://regex101.com/r/SguEAU/1

Then, you can use a list comprehension with `re.sub` to replace whitespace characters (including newlines) in every captured substring with a single normal space:

```
test ="""
    [
    "this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."
    ],
    [
    "like *.;#]§< and many "" more."
    ],
    [
    "plus there are even
newlines

in it."
    ]"""

output = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'(?s)\[[^"]*"(.*?)"[^]"]*\]', test)]
```

Result:

```
['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.', 'like *.;#]§< and many "" more.', 'plus there are even newlines in it.']
```

Comment: Thanks your regex worked just fine for the example.
Only when i tried it on my textfile, it had sometimes problem capturing text, when there are patterns with Quotes in it.
But also your hint with the list comprehension was very helpful. I combined it with the approach from Krishna and it seems to work well on my textfile.

Comment: I'm curious, for what sort of input did the regex fail? The `s` flag plus `.*?` should have accounted for all situations, I would've thought